# How to locate an Angular element in Selenium?

Tags: c#, angular, selenium-webdriver

I have the following HTML

```
    <div class="dx-filterbuilder-action-icon dx-icon-plus dx-filterbuilder-action" tabindex="0">
         ::before 
    </div>
```

I have tried locating this as follows in Selenium C#

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'dx-filterbuilder-action-icon dx-icon-plus dx-filterbuilder-action']")
```

but the test is failing saying it could not Find Element. I'm trying to click the '+' element shown in the image below.

Not sure what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing that is getting dynamically added (looks like by devexpress). I'd imagine that is your issue. We'll need a [mcve]

Comment: yep its devexpress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the element is added dynamically, you need to wait until the element is in the dom.

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
wait.Until(x=> x.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'dx-filterbuilder-action-icon dx-icon-plus dx-filterbuilder-action']"));
```

Instead of putting x.FindElement in the lamba, you can directly do a click. It basically repeats your action until it gets non-null non-exception response, or it timeouts. Giving time for DOM to update.